# Unable to pick color option?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I am new to blender and trying to start off simple with minecraft animations. I am watching a video tutorial about how to change a character's "skin", it's easy if the options are enabled but it seems mine are not. I was wondering how do I enable these options?

This first image is what I see:

[image]

This second image is what I am trying to achieve but the options are not there:

[image]

I hope this is an easy fix, thank you in advance. I am using cycles render and the latest version of blender (downloaded blender yesterday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected the wrong shader.

[image]

Click on *Mix Shader* and select *Diffuse BSDF* instead.

Comment: It made the guy entirely white besides his eyes and eyebrows, http://i.imgur.com/a6rp951.jpg - I figured it out, you need to change the color option to "image texture" and go from there in terms of setting the skin. Thank you very much Photon! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun with Blender :)